# Dynamic SQL: Grouping by one variable, counting another for column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am trying to do a dynamic sql query, similar to some that have appeared on this forum, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to work.

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table with a series of order_ref numbers.  Each of these numbers has a varying number of advice_refs associated with it. advice_ref numbers are unique (they are a key from another table). There is at least one advice_ref for each order_ref.  There are a bunch of columns that describe information for each advice_ref.

What I want to do is create a table with a row for each unique order_ref, with columns for each advice_ref, in ascending order. The columns would be Advice01, Advice02, ....Advice10, Advice11, etc. Not all the Advice# columns would be filled in for every order_ref and the number of advice# columns would depend on the order_ref with the greatest number of advice_refs.

The table would look like:

```
Order Advice01  Advice02  Advice03  Advice04.....
  1       1         2         3        
  2       5         8         9        20
  3       25
```

The code I've tried to use is:

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @PVT NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ', COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME('Advice' + RowNum) + ', '''') AS ' +  QUOTENAME('Advice' + RowNum),
            @PVT = @PVT + ', ' + QUOTENAME('Advice' + RowNum)
    FROM    (SELECT case when RowNum2 < 10 then '0'+RowNum2 when RowNum2 >=10 then RowNum2 end [RowNum] From
    (   SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_ref ORDER BY advice_ref)) [RowNum2]
                FROM    [ED_dups].[dbo].[NewEDDupsLongForm]
            ) rn2 ) rn

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT order_ref' + @SQL + '
                FROM    (   SELECT  order_ref, 
                                    advice_ref, 
                                    case when CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_ref ORDER BY advice_ref)) < 10 
                                         then ''Advice0'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_ref ORDER BY advice_ref))
                                         else ''Advice'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_ref ORDER BY advice_ref)) 
                                         end [AdviceID]
                            FROM    [ED_dups].[dbo].[NewEDDupsLongForm]
                        ) data
                        PIVOT
                        (   MAX(advice_ref)
                            FOR AdviceID IN (' + STUFF(@PVT, 1, 2, '') + ')
                        ) pvt'

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

SQL server tells me that the query executed successfully, but there is no output.  When I run snippets of the code, it seems that the problem either lies in the pivot statement, near 
`+ STUFF(@PVT, 1, 2, '') + ')`
and/or in the select statement, near 
`''Advice0'' +`

Thanks in advance for any help--I've been at this for days!

Comment: Do your values look as you'd expect them to when you `PRINT @SQL` at each step?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to initialize variables like

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @PVT NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
```

or

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PVT NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = '', @PVT = ''
```

Otherwise your `@SQL` would be null

Comment: Good catch, I agree. `NULL` + anything = `NULL`

Comment: @GoatCO I've encountered this problems so many times in the past :)

Comment: Woot!  That really helped.  Now I just need to figure out how to get the columns to be in numerical order.

Comment: @user2811528 I think you can change your last string to `) rn2 ) rn order by RowNum`

Answer (score 0):

fist thing that comes to my mind is - do you really need SQL to fetch you dataset with dynamic number of columns? If you are writting an application, then your user interface, being it a web page or desktop app form, would be much nicer place to transform your data into a desired structure.

If you really need to do so, you will make your life much easier when you will not try to do everything in one big and rather complicated query, but rather split it into smaller tasks done step by step. What I would do is to use temporary tables to store working results, then use cursors to process order by order and advice by advice while inserting my data into temporary table or tables, in the end return a content of this table. Wrap everything in a stored procedure.
This method will also allow you to debug it easier - you can check every single step if it has done what it was expected to do.

And final advice - share a definition of your NewEDDupsLongForm table - someone might write some code to help you out then.

cheers